# MIT 6.1810 Lab Utils xargs Issue: Unexpected Output with find . b | xargs echo

Tags: c, xv6

I’m working on the [MIT 6.1810’s Lab Utils](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2023/labs/util.html). While testing the xargs functionality using `make qemu`, I encountered a weird issue.

When I execute the following commands:

```bash
echo hello > b
find . b | xargs echo
```

the output appears as follow:

```bash
buf:./b 0
./b
buf:
/b 1
```

Typically, the output of **`find . b`** would be:

```bash
./b
```

However, when I directly run `echo ./b` (whose output matches `find . b`), the result of `find . b | xargs echo`  is different from the previous case:

```bash
buf:./b
 0
./b
```

Furthermore, if I replace `write` with `printf` or `fprintf`, which normally prints the output to stdout by default or by setting file descriptor argument to 1, respectively. The output of `find . b | xargs echo` changes signficantly:

```bash
buf:. 0
.
buf:/b
 0
/b
```

It appears that during the first pass, the **`read`** function reads only the dot ('.'), and during the second pass, it reads the remaining string "/b".

These unexpected outputs have left me puzzled. I wonder why the outputs differ even though the input appears to be the same string, i.e., **`./b`**.

The normal output of the following command should be `./b`.

```bash
find . b | xargs echo
```

For my implementation with debug printf, the correct output should be:

```bash
buf:./b
 0
./b
```

which is the same as `echo ./b | xargs echo`.

**My implementation for find:**

```c
struct dirent de;
struct stat st;
fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
fstat(fd, &st);
while (read(fd, &de, sizeof(de)) == sizeof(de))
    memmove(p, de.name, DIRSIZ);
    p[DIRSIZ] = 0;
    stat(buf, &st);
    switch (st.type)
    {
    case T_FILE:
        if (strcmp(de.name, name) == 0)
        {
            write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
            write(1, "\n", 1);
            //printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
        break;
    ...
    }
}
```

**Echo’s implementation (supplied by the course):**

```c
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    write(1, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]);
    if (i + 1 < argc)
    {
        write(1, " ", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    }
}
```

**My implementation for xargs:**

```c
    int _argc = 0;
  char *args[MAXARG];

  char buf[1024];
  char *p;

  while (read(0, buf, sizeof(buf)) != 0)
  {
    printf("buf:%s %d\n", buf, *buf == '\n');
    _argc = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      args[_argc++] = argv[i];
    }
    p = buf;
    while (_argc <= MAXARG && *p != '\0')
    {
      char *tmp = strchr(p, ' ');
      if (tmp == 0)
      {
        tmp = strchr(p, '\n');
        if (tmp != 0)
          *tmp = '\0';
        args[_argc++] = p;
        break;
      }
      *tmp = '\0';
      args[_argc++] = p;
      p = tmp + 1;
    }

    if (fork() == 0)
      exec(args[0], args);
    else
      wait(0);
  }

  exit(0);
```

Comment: `find . b` will first print everything in `.` recursively, then everything in `b` recursively. So the output should be `. ./b b`

Comment: It looks like your expected output is for `find . -name b`, not `find . b`.

Comment: `read()` doesn't read line by line. It reads up to `sizeof(buf)` bytes, but it can return less. `xargs` needs to buffer up the data, and print when it gets whitespace or EOF.